# Order Of Growth complicated for loops

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

For the following code fragment, what is the order of growth in terms of N?

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i = i*2)
  for (int j = 1; j <= N; j = j*2)
    for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
        sum++;
```

I have figured that there is lgN term, but I am stuck on evaluating this part : lgN(1 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ....). What will the last term of the sequence be? I need the last term to calculate the sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a geometric progression in your outer loops, so there is a closed form for the sum of which you want to take the log:

```
1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^N = 2^(N+1) - 1
```

To be precise, your sum is

```
1 + ... + 2^(floor(ld(N))
```

with `ld` denoting the logarithm to base 2.

The outer two loops are independent from each other, while the innermost loop only depends on `i`. There is a single operation (increment) in the innermost loop, which means that the number of visits to the innermost loop equals the summation result.

```
  \sum_i=1..( floor(ld(N)) ) {
      \sum_j=1..( floor(ld(N)) ) {
          \sum_k=1..2^i { 1 }
      }
  }

    // adjust innermost summation bounds   
= \sum_i=1..( floor(ld(N)) ) {
      \sum_j=1..( floor(ld(N)) ) {
          -1 + \sum_k=0..2^i { 1 }
      }
  }

    // swap outer summations and resolve innermost summation
= \sum_j=1..( floor(ld(N)) ) {
      \sum_i=1..( floor(ld(N)) ) {
          2^i
      }
  }

   // resolve inner summation
= \sum_j=1..( floor(ld(N)) ) {
      2^(floor(ld(N)) + 1) - 2
  }

   // resolve outer summation
= ld(N) * N - 2 * floor(ld(N))
```

This amounts to `O(N log N)` ( the second term in the expression vanishes asymptotically wrt to the first ) in  Big-Oh notation.

Comment: I have a problem with the answer that `O(.)-O(.)` is not defined. What is it? A set substraction? (Obviously not...) Please fix this issue and I'll gladly upvote.

Comment: @amit. You are perfectly right. The symbolism is meant to express that one time complexity dominates the other but actually it abuses notation. Correcting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the outer loop will take `log N` steps, the next loop will also take `log N` steps, and the innermost loop will take at most `N` steps (although this is a very rough bound). In total, the loop has a runtime complexity of at most `((log N)^2)*N`, which can probably be improved.

Comment: It is also `O(n!)`, but that's not very informative... The bound, as you said, is not tight, see @collapsar answer to understand how one should compute it here.